# std::vector::reserve performance penalty

Tags: c++, performance, stl, stdvector

```
inline void add(const DataStruct& rhs) {
   using namespace boost::assign;
   vec.reserve(vec.size() + 3);
   vec += rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c;
}
```

The above function was executed for about 17000 times and it performed (as far as I can see. There was some transformation involved) about 2 magnitudes worse **with** the call to vector::reserve.

I always was under the impression that reserve can speed up push_back even for small values but this doesn't seem true and I can't find any obvious reasons why it shouldn't be this way. Does reserve prevent the inlining of the function? Is the call to size() too expensive? Does this depend on the platform? I'll try and code up some small benchmark to confirm this in a clean environment.

Compiler: `gcc (GCC) 4.4.2` with -g -O2

Comment: Have you tried reserving space for 17000*3 inputs? There may be some overhead with your extra function call, which could account for the difference.

Comment: @splicer: The number was due to the testdata. The actual number of calls is variable.

Comment: my point was that what you're doing is only efficient with larger numbers. James Schek's answer gives you a way to do it with a variable number of calls, so long as you know the total to start with. otherwise you're better off letting the default implementation handle it for you.

Comment: Are you calling add() on the same class instance? In that case you are growing vec by 3 for each add whereas pushback by itself would grow vec far less frequently.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

GCC implementation of `reserve()` will allocate exact number of elements, while `push_back()` will grow internal buffer exponentially by doubling it, so you are defeating the exponential growth and forcing reallocation/copy on each iteration. Run your test under `ltrace` or `valgrind` and see the number of `malloc()` calls.

Comment: +1. I have just checked GCC sources and been going to write the same.

Comment: Is the exponential growth of the buffer through push_back() guaranteed by the standard or implementation defined?

Comment: No, exponential growth is not guaranteed by the standard, it's an implementation detail, same as this particular behavior of reserve().

Comment: Exponential growth IS effectively guaranteed by the standard, as it's the only reasonable way to get amortized O(1) behavior for push_back (unreasonable solutions include allocating all memory ;) )

Comment: The behavior of GCC can be explained too: by letting you set exactly the expected size, they allow you the opportunity of not wasting memory in cases where you know actually how much you'll need.

Comment: I always figured the exponential growth applied to `reserve` too, and that `reserve` just guaranteed element allocation would just preallocate and not fail later with a `push_back` due to exhausted memory. Encountering the asker's same surprise today, I kinda wish there was a `reserve` variant that guaranteed later allocation (for POD's at least) but would still exhibit the natural growth.

Comment: In case it matters to you, beware that "exponential" doesn't always mean doubling the capacity on `emplace_back` - some implementations grow to 1.5x.

Answer (score 7):

Use only reserve if you know in advance how much place it will use.

Reserve will need to copy your whole vector...

If you do a push_back and the vector is too small, then it will do a reserve (vec.size()*2).

If you don't know beforehand how big your vector is going to be and if you need random access, consider using std::deque.

Comment: It's not an heuristic. Is proved that on average the insertion of a new element is O(1). Read any book on amortized analysis (eg. Introduction to Algorithms).

Comment: well.. I think it would be fair to say that it's a heuristic that mathematically proven to have the best performance in the average case.

Comment: You can prove the same with multiplying by 3 instead of two. But I'll edit it anyways if it bothers you that much.

Comment: I would say it is neither a heurstic nor an algorithm.  It is a strategy that works well for a lot of usage scenarios.

Comment: I read something somewhere that multiplying by 1.5 worked better.  I don't remember where, what assumptions they were making, or anything like that.  Obviously, multiplying by a bigger constant reduces the number of reallocations and uses memory less efficiently.

Comment: It is also true, that, for multiplying size by `n` on exhaust, one additional copy is made for each `n-1` push_back calls
Therefore, multiplying for 1.5 works exactly *twice* slower.

Comment: Multiplying the current allocated size by any constant (besides 0) will result in logarithmic growth.  Changing the constant is just tuning, Big O performance is still the same.  1.5 favors smaller vectors, 2 favors larger.  They chose 2 because it is a nice round number in computer land, and any tuning would be meaningless as my usage will differ from yours.  If you need tune the behavior you can easily subvert the default behavior using size() and reserve().

Comment: "They chose 2" - who? Dinkumware chose 1.5. Note that Pavel Shved's analysis is wrong (probably due to poor wording). If you grow a million element vector by a factor `n==1.5`, then you can obviously add 500.000 elements, not`n-1==0.5`

Comment: Facebook's implementation of `std::vector` uses a value less than 2 so that the container could theoretically 'reuse' space left over from previous allocations. A growth factor of 2 guarantees that the space required for each allocation is always a bit more than the sum of all space you've allocated so far (by `sizeof(T)` bytes), which means that the vector will always creep forward in memory, assuming the implementation allocates memory linearly. A growth factor less than 2 can use space that previous allocations have given up.

Answer (score 7):

You only use `reserve()` if you know in advance the number of elements. In that case `reserve()` space for all elements at once.

Otherwise just use `push_back()` and rely on the default strategy - it will reallocate exponentially and greatly reduce the number of reallocations at a cost of slightly suboptimal memory consumption.

Answer (score 5):

When std::vector needs to reallocate it grows its allocation size by N*2, where n is its current size.  This results in a logarithmic number of reallocs as the vector grows.

If instead the std::vector grew its allocated space by a constant amount, the number of reallocs would grow linearly as the vector grows.

What you've done is essentially cause the vector to grow by a constant amount 3, meaning linear growth.  Linear is obviously worse that logarithmic, especially with big numbers.

Generally, the only growth better than logarithmic is constant.  That is why the standards committee created the reserve method.  If you can avoid all reallocs (constant) you will perform better than the default logarithmic behavior.

That said you may want to consider Herb Sutter's comments about preferring std::deque over vector [www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Move the reserve outside of the add.

Each time you invoke "add", you are reserving atleast 3 extra elements. Depending on the implementation of vector, this *could* be increasing the size of the backing array almost every time you call "add". That is would definately cause the performance difference that you describe.

The correct way to use reserve is something like:

```
vec.reserve(max*3);
for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
   add(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you profiled the code I bet you would see that the += IS very fast, the problem is the reserve is killing you.  You should really only use reserve when you have some knowledge of how big the vector will grow to.  If you can guess ahead of time then do ONE reserve, otherwise just go with the default push_back.