# C++ standard vector resize() function

Tags: c++, resize, stdvector

resize() adds/removes elements based on the size given to it. reserve() reserves memory space and it will not reallocate memory. The question I have is whether resize also works the same as in the capacity of the vector will only not increase?

To add, would a combination of:

```
 std::vector<X> vector;
 vector.reserve(5);
 vector.resize(5);
```

make any sense? Is it redundant? The goal here is to be able to overwrite values in the vector without having the vector allocate any extra space.

Comment: As a test, using Visual Studio I noted that the capacity remains the same for bot resize and reserve. However, this could be some optimization on part of VS's compiler.

Comment: *"reserve() reserves memory space and it will not reallocate memory"* -- Is that supposed to be a question? Because if it's a statement, it's wrong.

Comment: *reserve() reserves memory space and it will not reallocate memory*.  Who told you that?  `reserve` will allocate more memory if the size requested is greater than the capacity.

Comment: May be you shoud start by reading http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize and  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve ?

Comment: Short and very simplified, `reserve` sets the capacity and `resize` sets the size (and possibly the capacity as well).

Comment: yes my question is basically the 'possibly' part. Will resize() cap the capacity to avoid further capacity increases?

Comment: In order to "overwrite values in the vector without having the vector allocate any extra space" you do not need any of these. just use `vector[i] = x` to overwrite a value.

Comment: "reserve() reserves memory space and it will not reallocate memory" appears to be nonsense under all reasonable interpretations. C++ does not have a concept of reserving an address range (like virtual allocation). And `reserve` will necessarily allocate a new buffer if the capacity isn't already already as large as the call specifies.

Comment: Obtain a grounded understanding of _abstraction_ and you will understand `std::vector` ... and the rest of C++. "Size" has many meanings, all of them based on context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this site](https://frogatto.com/2009/11/17/how-cs-vector-works-the-gritty-details/):

- `resize()`: This lets you change the size of the vector to any size you want.

  - It will fill the underlying buffer with elements.
- `reserve()`: This changes the capacity of the vector. Note that this doesn’t change the vector’s size, it just changes the size of the underlying buffer, to give more room for expansion of the buffer before the buffer has to be resized. Unlike calling `resize()`, this doesn’t change the behavior of the program, just the performance (Subsequent use of the reserved space will not incur a performance penalty for incremental reservations).

  - It will not limit the size of the buffer. If the buffer runs out of space it will automatically reallocate as needed.

[image]

> The question I have is whether resize also works the same as in the
>   capacity of the vector will only not increase?
>   To add, would a combination of :
>
> ```
>  std::vector<X> vector;
>  vector.reserve(5);
>  vector.resize(5);
> ```
>
> make any sense? Is it redundant?

`vector.reserve(5);` Would be redundant in this case.

> The goal here is to be able to overwrite values in the vector without
>   having the vector allocate any extra space.

For this goal it depends on how you want to overwrite the values.

- If you are planning to write directly by index, then you must use `resize()`.
- If you are using `push_back()`, then `reserve()` would be better so that you can avoid creating `X` twice.

Keep in mind that the algorithm used for the automatic reservation is implementation defined. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1742859/1460794) for more regarding the performance aspect.

Comment: "Unlike calling resize(), this doesn’t change the behavior of the program, just the performance." ...can you explain what you mean here?

Comment: Subsequent use of the reserved space will not incur a performance penalty for incremental reservations.

Comment: I would say that in your answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Updated with the clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where you got your info about `reserve`, but it will reallocate if the number you pass to it is greater than the vector's current capacity, as reported by the `capacity` function.

As for `resize`, it is required to set the number of elements, and if there isn't enough space in the capacity, it will also require a reallocation.

As for your code snippet:

```
std::vector<X> vector;
vector.reserve(5);
vector.resize(5);
```

This might make sense if you want to allocate the minimum amount possible in order to store 5 elements. The reason I say that is because `resize` might allocate more in anticipation for more additions later on (to be clear, this can only happen if the requested size is greater than the capacity. `resize` will never cause a reallocation if the requested size <= capacity). `reserve` on the other hand, usually just allocates exactly enough. It is allowed to allocate more, but I have never seen an implementation which does that.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between them is that resize lets you change the size (either increase or decrease) while reserve only reserves memory from the system. Resize initialises allocated memory with either a call to default constructor or copy constructor based on form of the resize used.

Both may cause memory reallocation.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @BenjaminLindley's answer, in GCC there is definitely a difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> a, b;

  for (std::size_t i=0; i<20; ++i)
  {
    a.reserve(i); a.resize(i); // a: reserve-then-resize
    b.resize(i);               // b: resize directly
    std::cout << a.capacity() << "\t" << b.capacity() << "\n";
  }
}
```

The output ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/434b5e92dff1575f)):

```
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   4
4   4
5   8
6   8
7   8
8   8
9   16
10  16
11  16
12  16
13  16
14  16
15  16
16  16
17  32
18  32
19  32
```

So, at least for gcc, reserve-then-resize results in *exactly* the capacity you asked for, while the direct resize “plans ahead” for expected future allocations.

Comment: I like this. Nice to see some actual testing of what would happen. It seems `push_back()` [triggers the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1605bba4ad5fa792) `reserve()` behavior as `b`.

Comment: Yes, I would have expected that. Repeated `push_back()`s are probably the most common use case for `std::vector`, and growing the capacity in exponential steps is what gives you _amortized_ O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

In some implementations, `resize` will almost certainly call `reserve` first. Having recently implemented a variant of `std::vector`, below is a stripped down and annotated version of [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)... (The comments are for the OP's understanding) *...In reality most STL implementations will be slightly more complex than this (for debugging purposes); but its largely the same concept.*

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::reserve(SizeType sz){
        //if only the new size is greater than current capacity
        if(sz > m_capacity){

            //allocate the new size
            T* data = static_cast<T*>(SFAllocator<T>::allocate(sz));

            //move all previous data
            for(SizeType i=0; i < m_size; i++){
                new(data+i) T(std::move(m_data[i]));  //! TODO: move if only noexcept;

                //call the destructor on the moved item
                call_destructor(m_data[i]);
            }

            //deallocate formerly used memory
            SFAllocator<T>::deallocate(m_data);

            //reassign the capacity to the new capacity
            m_capacity = sz;

            m_data = data; //reassign the data pointer
            //size remains the same
        }
```

And below is a stripped down and annotated version of [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). As you can see below, `resize` has a call to `reserve` first.

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::resize(SizeType sz){
    // resize it to fit at least fit to "sz"
    reserve(sz);

    //if higher size is requested
    if(sz > m_size)
        //default construct the remainder of the new uninitialized memory
        for(SizeType i= m_size; i < sz; i++)
            new(m_data+i) T{}

    //if the container size is to get smaller
    else  
        for(SizeType i=sz; i<m_size; i++)
            call_destructor(m_data[i]);  //delete the elements at indexes above "sz"

    m_size = sz;  //change container size.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does C++ 11 call it?

Comment: Facebook's Folly's FBVector, a drop in replacement for `std::vector` calls `reserve` inside `resize`... https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/FBVector.h#L919

Comment: Note, C++ is a language, STL is it's default library. Compiler products typically bundle an implementation with the actual compiler. Like, .........GCC libstdc++........... Clang --> libcxx,............ MSVC --> Dinkumware...

Comment: I just checked GCC 4.6's libstdc++, And yes it calls it(a variant of resize)

Comment: @WhiZTiM [Is STL mentioned in the C++ standard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5205491/1460794)? :p

Comment: @flatmouse, Ohh... Forgive my not being pedantic with words in the legalese sense... Though I view it the same thing... I meant the C++ Standard Library.. :-) ... Thanks

Comment: @WhiZTiM I know, I know... I just couldn't resist. Sadly a fun Q&A like the one I linked to are no longer on topic for SO.